# SPARQL: get all Predicates and their respective Objects and organize them into a List

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am looking for a way to add the results of this query into a 2D String List using Jena framework.

```
 sparqlQueryString="
    select distinct ?p ?o where 
       {
         <http://dbpedia.org/resource/NVA_(film)> ?p ?o
       }
  ";
```

in a way where the first row contains the properties and second their respective instances. The problem is that a property may have many instances.

```
    List<List<String>> results= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString);
    qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
    s = qexec.execSelect();
    res = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(s);
     while(res.hasNext())
            {
                QuerySolution so = res.nextSolution();
                results.add(so.getResource("p").toString());
                // The part I am looking for to add instance

            }


    // the results expected
    results.get(0) = http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
    results.get(0).get(0) =     http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/2005Films
    results.get(0).get(1) =     http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
    results.get(0).get(2) =     http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Work
```

Comment: Server side solution: SPARQL 1.1 feature GROUP_CONCAT (see the W3C recommendation for examples). Client side solution: Java basics.

Comment: Your expected results don't make sense.  You have .get(0) returning a property, and then .get(0).get(0) returning an object value.  But the first get(0) returned a property, not a list of object values.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd suggest using a Map<String,Set<String>> to take properties to sets of values.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you're right, I just used it as prototype. I created two lists instead with the same indexes to get the objects.

Comment: @M20 You commented, "AKSW Thanks, it worked."  If you got a solution to this working, please post it as an answer (and mark it as accepted) so that others can benefit if they come across this question. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AKSW : Server side solution: SPARQL 1.1 feature GROUP_CONCAT (see the W3C recommendation for examples). Client side solution: Java basics.